# Scraping a HTML list in Node.js

Tags: jquery, list, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm new to web scraping and jquery.

I have an HTML page with a list of posts. I want to load all the associated dates (class `date`) as well as the number of stars the user gave (count of the classes `star`).

I have tried the following Node.JS script using cheerio but so far can't load any date. I guess it has to deal with the tree I am not parsing properly but can't figure out yet.

Any tip, please?

**Html page**

```
<body>
   <og:iframe src="...">
      <div id="page">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content" class="clearfix">
               <div id="main2col" class="clearfix">
                  <ul class="parts-list clearfix-parent">
                    <li>
                       <div class="contents-right505">
                          <div class="clearfix">
                             <p class="info">
                                <span class="date">2019/06/18 22:02</span>
                                by&nbsp;<a id="aaaa" href="/userid/123">xxx</a>
                             </p>
                          </div>
                          <span class="value">
                              yyy：
                              <span>
                                  <span class="star"></span>
                                  <span class="star"></span>
                                  <span class="star"></span>
                                  <span class="star"></span>
                                  <span class="star"></span>
                              </span>
                          </span>
                       </div>
                    </li>
```

**Node.JS code extract**

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
const $ = require('cheerio');

const pageParse = function (url) {
    return rp(url)
        .then(function(html) {
            $('parts-list')
            .find('li > div.contents-right505 > clearfix')
            .each(function() {
                var $el = $(this);
                console.log('date:', $el.attr('date'));
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct when you say your selectors are not working properly.
First problem is, we have no idea what is `parts-list`. Is it an id? A class?
So, assuming it's an id, this should work for you:

```js
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

const pageParse = (url) =>
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(html => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            $('#parts-list .date').each(() => console.log($(this).html()));
            $('#parts-list .value').each(() => console.log($('span .star').length));
        });
```

Cheerio is an implementation of jQuery, so parsing the html tree is like writing a css selector.

[edit]
Just noticed you're also not loading the html you got from the crawler to cheerio. Basically that means cheerio never has the html tree.
PS: wrote my sample with `node-fetch`, but my guess is that your only problem is actually the selector.
[/edit]

Comment: Thank you so much! And apologies for not putting the full html, was trying to simplify. Just added the full tree, see the update. Will try what you are recommending and will revert. Thanks again!

Comment: I can't yet make it working. The result I get in the console are "null". Trying this though in debug gives me the correct value: $('.parts-list .date').first().html() --> "2019/03/29 10:32"

Comment: $('.parts-list .date').text() yields the dates, but can't solve the 'stars'. Also sure that it's not the way to go but can't yet understand how this works (not much doc on the cheerio site)

Comment: If you want to try, this is the url https://minkara.carview.co.jp/partsreview/review.aspx?mk=1200&br=46556&id=231929&pn=2